Will dried tomatoes have the taste of tomato gel?
When tomatoes are dried via the sun or whatever method, does the taste of the gel get concentrated in the dried tomatoe?
I read that the umami taste of the gel is due to glutamic acid and dried tomatoes are concentrated sources of glutamic acid so I imagine the answer is yes.
However I’ve also read that dried tomatoes lose a lot of their tomato flavour so wondering if this refers to a loss of the gel taste or other taste?  Why does this happen?
Thanks.

I suppose you could dissect a tomato (or more likely a bunch of tomatoes) and dry the "parts" separately if you wanted to. The "gel" will take a heck of a lot to make anything appreciable when dried - that portion shrinks the most in drying because it's mostly water.

You should note that tomatoes taste different depending on the temperature you use to dry them. If you want them to taste more like fresh ones you would use a lower temperature. This isn't to say they taste exactly the same as fresh ones.

There is a load of umami in any form of tomato.  However, at least to my taste, different forms of tomato taste quite different.  Dried tomato does not taste like the inside of a fresh tomato. To be clearer with respect to your question, the taste of tomato gets concentrated when dried...the entire tomato.  It would be easier to decipher taste differences of tomato parts when the tomato is fresh.
